# Dealer put on a different tire than the rest, is this bad?

Tags: tires, vw, jetta

I got a flat a few days ago and took it to the dealer to be fixed. He asked if I wanted the same tires and I said yes.

I just got it back yesterday, and saw today that it is not the same tire.

My other 3 tires are Hankook Optimo H727 P205/55R16 89T.

The one they put on is a Hankook Optimo H725b P205/55R16 89H.

I tried googling some comparisons but could not find anything useful.

They don't open for another 3 hours so I can't call and ask what's going on just yet. I would just like to know if this is worse than I think it is.

The whole reason I noticed was because when I woke up my low tire pressure signal was on so I checked my tire and it was at 20psi...not sure if that was just a coincidence or if that actually has something to do with it being the wrong tire.

I drive a 2010 VW Jetta TDI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dimensionally, the two tires are the same.

The only difference between the two is the [speed rating](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=35):

- **`H`** indicates that the tire can be safely used for speeds up to 130 mph (210 km/h)
- **`T`** denotes tire suitability for speeds up to 118 mph ( 190 km/h )

So in terms of compatibility the new 'H' tire should be fine. The low pressure may be due to:

- underinflation at the tire shop
- manufacturing defect in the tire
- improper seating of the rim
- leak in the tire valve
- a puncture post-installation